# Power density of an EM wave in a vacuum

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

I know that the power density of an EM field is given in general by

$$ \mathbf{J}\cdot\mathbf{E}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\epsilon_o}{2}\mathbf{E}^2+\frac{1}{2\mu_0}\mathbf{B}^2\right)-\nabla\cdot\left(\mathbf{E}\times\mathbf{B}\right)$$

I realized that for a pure EM plane wave in a vacuum I can calculate the RHS and get a value different from $0$, but in a vacuum I'd expect $\mathbf{J}\cdot\mathbf{E}=0$ because there are no currents. I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is not correct, you should have
$$\vec{J}\cdot\vec{E}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\varepsilon_{0}}{2}E^2+\frac{1}{2\mu_{0}}B^2\right)-\frac{1}{\mu_0}\vec{\nabla}\cdot\left(\vec{E}\times\vec{B}\right)$$
The RHS will indeed vanish for radiation in vacuum.

Comment: That wasn't a fun 2 hours fooling around with a wrong equation. Thank you.